# ggplot functions to replicate plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to replicate the theme of these graph using ggplot, I searched online to show me how to assign and I found few articles that discussed changing colors of two variables in scatterplot, I tried the following:

```
d1<-read.csv("./data/games.csv")
p.1<-ggplot(d1, aes(x=cream_rating, y=charcoal_rating)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = cream_rating))
p.1 + ggtitle("Rating of Cream vs Charcoal") +
  xlab("rating of cream") + ylab("rating of charcoal")+ theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + scale_color_manual(
                        values=c("orange", "green"))
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale

Traceback:
1. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
2. tryCatch(withCallingHandlers({
 .     if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr)) 
 .         stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
 .     rpr <- repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
 .     if (is.null(rpr)) 
 .         return(NULL)
 .     prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
 . }, error = error_handler), error = outer_handler)
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
6. withCallingHandlers({
 .     if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr)) 
 .         stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
 .     rpr <- repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
 .     if (is.null(rpr)) 
 .         return(NULL)
 .     prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
 . }, error = error_handler)
7. repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
8. repr_text.default(obj)
9. paste(capture.output(print(obj)), collapse = "\n")
10. capture.output(print(obj))
11. evalVis(expr)
12. withVisible(eval(expr, pf))
13. eval(expr, pf)
14. eval(expr, pf)
15. print(obj)
16. print.ggplot(obj)
17. ggplot_build(x)
18. ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
19. lapply(data, scales_train_df, scales = npscales)
20. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
21. lapply(scales$scales, function(scale) scale$train_df(df = df))
22. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
23. scale$train_df(df = df)
24. f(..., self = self)
25. self$train(df[[aesthetic]])
26. f(..., self = self)
27. self$range$train(x, drop = self$drop, na.rm = !self$na.translate)
28. f(..., self = self)
29. scales::train_discrete(x, self$range, drop = drop, na.rm = na.rm)
30. stop("Continuous value supplied to discrete scale", call. = FALSE)
```

I'm using the wrong function, which one that I should use and how to get the cross line in the middle?

```
structure(list(rated = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), turns = c(13L, 16L, 61L, 61L, 95L, 
5L, 33L, 9L, 66L, 119L), victory_status = structure(c(3L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("draw", "mate", "outoftime", 
"resign"), class = "factor"), winner = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("charcoal", "cream", 
"draw"), class = "factor"), increment_code = structure(c(3L, 
7L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("10+0", "15+0", 
"15+2", "15+30", "20+0", "30+3", "5+10"), class = "factor"), 
    cream_rating = c(1500L, 1322L, 1496L, 1439L, 1523L, 1250L, 
    1520L, 1413L, 1439L, 1381L), charcoal_rating = c(1191L, 1261L, 
    1500L, 1454L, 1469L, 1002L, 1423L, 2108L, 1392L, 1209L)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is what I want to achieve:[image]

I tried Stefan's suggestion (which was great help) with some modifications:

```
`d1<-read.csv("./data/games.csv")
ggplot(d1, aes(x=cream_rating, y=charcoal_rating)) + 
  # Map winner on color. Add some transparency in case of overplotting
  geom_point(aes(color = winner), alpha = 0.2) +
  # Add the cross: Add geom_pints with one variable fixed on its mean
  geom_point(aes(x = mean(cream_rating), color = winner), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point(aes(y = mean(charcoal_rating), color = winner), alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 17)) +
  # "draw"s should be dropped and removed from the title
  scale_color_manual(values = c(cream = "seagreen4", charcoal = "chocolate3", draw = NA)) +
  ggtitle("Rating of Cream vs Charcoal") +
  xlab("rating of cream") + ylab("rating of charcoal") + theme_bw() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

I want to filter out "draw" from the plot, also when I change the dot shapes to triangles and circle, they don't seem to be changing, in addition I get this error:

```
Warning message:
“Removed 950 rows containing missing values (geom_point).”
Warning message:
“Removed 950 rows containing missing values (geom_point).”
Warning message:
“Removed 950 rows containing missing values (geom_point).”
```

One more thing that I noticed, I get double cross instead of one!

This is my output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you mapped a continuous variable (`cream_rating`) on a discrete color scale (`scale_color_manual`).

1. As the plots in your images show there are only two colors, i.e. we need a discrete variable. As your data is about ratings my guess is that to achieve the plots you have to map `winner` on color. One question remains: How about `draw`s. In my code below I set the color for draws equal to NA, i.e draws are dropped. But you can change that as you like.
2. From the image I also guess that some transparency was used to tackle overplotting. This could be achieved via the `alpha` argument, which I set to 0.6.
3. Concerning the cross appearing in your plot. Hard to tell, but my guess is that here the data was "replicated" two times by fixing one of your ratings variables to its `mean`value. If this guess is correct, we can get the cross via two additional `geom_point` layers.

```r
library(ggplot2)

d1 <- structure(list(rated = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
                         TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), turns = c(13L, 16L, 61L, 61L, 95L, 
                                                             5L, 33L, 9L, 66L, 119L), victory_status = structure(c(3L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                   2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("draw", "mate", "outoftime", 
                                                                                                                                                               "resign"), class = "factor"), winner = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("charcoal", "cream", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "draw"), class = "factor"), increment_code = structure(c(3L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   7L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("10+0", "15+0", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "15+2", "15+30", "20+0", "30+3", "5+10"), class = "factor"), 
               cream_rating = c(1500L, 1322L, 1496L, 1439L, 1523L, 1250L, 
                                1520L, 1413L, 1439L, 1381L), charcoal_rating = c(1191L, 1261L, 
                                                                                 1500L, 1454L, 1469L, 1002L, 1423L, 2108L, 1392L, 1209L)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                         10L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(d1, aes(x=cream_rating, y=charcoal_rating)) + 
  # Map winner on color. Add some transparency in case of overplotting
  geom_point(aes(color = winner), alpha = 0.6) +
  # Just a guess to add the cross: Add geom_pints with one variable fixed on its mean
  geom_point(aes(x = mean(cream_rating), color = winner), alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_point(aes(y = mean(charcoal_rating), color = winner), alpha = 0.6) +
  # Should "draw"s be colored or dropped?
  scale_color_manual(values = c(cream = "green", charcoal = "orange", draw = NA)) +
  ggtitle("Rating of Cream vs Charcoal") +
  xlab("rating of cream") + ylab("rating of charcoal")+ theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

1. the shapes don't show up because you missed to map `winner` on the `shape` aes
2. the "errors" are simply warnings which arise because we set the color for `draw`s to NA. These are the rows which ggplot removes. To get rid of the `draw`s simply filter your dataset before plotting:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

d1 %>% 
  filter(winner != "draw") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cream_rating, y=charcoal_rating, color = winner, shape = winner)) + 
  # Map winner on color. Add some transparency in case of overplotting
  geom_point(alpha = 0.6, na.rm = TRUE) +
  # Just a guess to add the cross: Add geom_pints with one variable fixed on its mean
  geom_point(aes(x = mean(cream_rating)), alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_point(aes(y = mean(charcoal_rating)), alpha = 0.6) +
  # Should "draw"s be colored or dropped?
  scale_color_manual(values = c(cream = "green", charcoal = "orange")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(cream = 16, charcoal = 17)) +
  ggtitle("Rating of Cream vs Charcoal") +
  xlab("rating of cream") + ylab("rating of charcoal")+ theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Tank you so much @stefan, please see my question update, I appreciate your help and support.

Comment: Hi @user432797. I just made an edit to solve these issues. Best S.

Comment: Thank you so much @stefan ! but I'm still getting double cross, any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: can you check my other question regarding the same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64250052/fixing-elongated-figures-next-to-each-other-in-r

Comment: Concerning the double cross. I guess my "guess" was wrong. The datapoints on the cross are already part of your datasets (probably these are datapoints where one of the ratings were missing and were therefore imputed by the mean or median). To check this remove the two addtional geom_point layers I added. Concerning the other question. I'm  busy at the moment but I will check it later.

Comment: Thank you so much @stefan, I appreciate the support, I believe you are right, the second plot seems to have "draw" in it, and when I zoomed I was able to see the draw was assigned blue square shape.