# Fixing elongated figures next to each other in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to replicate the theme of these graph using ggplot, I searched online for articles and question to show me how to assign these plots the right size and position and also to assign the tight dot shape,  and I found few articles that discussed changing position, I tried the following:

```
d1<-read.csv("./data/games.csv")
p.1<-ggplot(d1, aes(x=cream_rating, y=charcoal_rating)) + 
  # Map winner on color. Add some transparency in case of overplotting
  geom_point(aes(color = winner), alpha = 0.2) +
  # Add the cross: Add geom_pints with one variable fixed on its mean
  geom_point(aes(x = mean(cream_rating), color = winner), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point(aes(y = mean(charcoal_rating), color = winner), alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 17)) +
  # "draw"s should be dropped and removed from the title
  scale_color_manual(values = c(cream = "seagreen4", charcoal = "chocolate3", draw = NA)) +
  ggtitle("Rating of Cream vs Charcoal") +
  xlab("rating of cream") + ylab("rating of charcoal") + theme_classic() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

I tried the following to place them together:

```
require(gridExtra)
plot.1<-p.1
plot.2<-ggExtra::ggMarginal(p.1, type = "histogram")
grid.arrange(plot.1, plot.2, ncol=3)
```

```
library(cowplot)

theme_set(theme_cowplot())

plot.1<-p.1
plot.2<-ggExtra::ggMarginal(p.1, type = "histogram")

plot_grid(plot.1, plot.2, labels = "AUTO")
```

```
cowplot::plot_grid(plot.1, plot.2, labels = "AUTO")
```

```
library(magrittr)
library(multipanelfigure)
figure1 <- multi_panel_figure(columns = 2, rows = 1, panel_label_type = "none")
# show the layout
figure1

figure1 %<>%
  fill_panel(plot.1, column = 1, row = 1) %<>%
  fill_panel(plot.2, column = 2, row = 1) %<>%
  
figure1
```

This is my data set structure:

```
structure(list(rated = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), turns = c(13L, 16L, 61L, 61L, 95L, 
5L, 33L, 9L, 66L, 119L), victory_status = structure(c(3L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("draw", "mate", "outoftime", 
"resign"), class = "factor"), winner = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("charcoal", "cream", 
"draw"), class = "factor"), increment_code = structure(c(3L, 
7L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("10+0", "15+0", 
"15+2", "15+30", "20+0", "30+3", "5+10"), class = "factor"), 
    cream_rating = c(1500L, 1322L, 1496L, 1439L, 1523L, 1250L, 
    1520L, 1413L, 1439L, 1381L), charcoal_rating = c(1191L, 1261L, 
    1500L, 1454L, 1469L, 1002L, 1423L, 2108L, 1392L, 1209L)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is what I want to achieve:[image]

I tried Stefan's suggestion (which was great help) with some modifications:

```
d1<-read.csv("./data/games.csv")
ggplot(d1, aes(x=cream_rating, y=charcoal_rating)) + 
  ##### Map winner on color. Add some transparency in case of overplotting
  geom_point(aes(color = winner), alpha = 0.2) +
  ##### Add the cross: Add geom_pints with one variable fixed on its mean
  geom_point(aes(x = mean(cream_rating), color = winner), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point(aes(y = mean(charcoal_rating), color = winner), alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 17)) +
  ##### "draw"s should be dropped and removed from the title
  scale_color_manual(values = c(cream = "seagreen4", charcoal = "chocolate3", draw = NA)) +
  ggtitle("Rating of Cream vs Charcoal") +
  xlab("rating of cream") + ylab("rating of charcoal") + theme_bw() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

I want to filter out "draw" from the plot, also when I change the dot shapes to triangles and circle, they don't seem to be changing, in addition I get this error:

```
Warning message:
“Removed 950 rows containing missing values (geom_point).”
Warning message:
“Removed 950 rows containing missing values (geom_point).”
Warning message:
“Removed 950 rows containing missing values (geom_point).”
```

One more thing that I noticed, I get double cross instead of one!

This is my output:
[image]

When I try the first code block in this question, I get long distorted figures not square next to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this fits your need. To glue the three plots together I make use of the `cowplot` package. The legend is probably still not perfect.

1. To get only one legend but still a nice alignment of the plots I made the legends for the first and the third plot "transparent" vis `guide_legend` and `theme` options
2. To make all plots the same size I added transparent marginals to the scatter plot
3. To fix the position and make the plots square I set the same limits for both axes via `xlim` and `ylim` and set the aspect ratio to 1 using `theme()`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(cowplot)

# Add a second draw to the example data to make the density work
d1 <- d1 %>% 
  add_row(winner = "draw", cream_rating = 1002, charcoal_rating = 1250)

# Get the limits

lims <- c(floor(min(d1$cream_rating, d1$charcoal_rating)), ceiling(max(d1$cream_rating, d1$charcoal_rating)))

p1 <- d1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cream_rating, y=charcoal_rating, color = winner, shape = winner)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2, na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(cream = "seagreen4", charcoal = "chocolate3", draw = "blue")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(cream = 16, charcoal = 17, draw = 15)) +
  xlim(lims) + 
  ylim(lims) +
  labs(x = "rating of cream", y = "rating of charcoal") + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.position = "bottom") +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)

p1_1 <- p1 +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = c(NA, NA, NA)))) +
  theme(legend.text = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank())

p1_1 <- ggExtra::ggMarginal(p1_1, type = "histogram",
                    margins = 'both',
                    size = 5,
                    position = "identity",
                    color = NA,
                    fill= NA)

p2 <- ggExtra::ggMarginal(p1, type = "histogram",
                             margins = 'both',
                             size = 5,
                             groupColour = TRUE,
                             groupFill = TRUE,
                             position = "identity"
)

# Make legend transparent
p1 <- p1 +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = c(NA, NA, NA)))) +
  theme(legend.text = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank())

p3 <- d1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cream_rating, y=charcoal_rating, color = winner, shape = winner)) + 
  geom_density_2d(na.rm = TRUE)  +
  geom_point(alpha = 0, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(cream = "seagreen4", charcoal = "chocolate3", draw = "blue")) +
  xlim(lims) + 
  ylim(lims) +
  labs(x = "rating of cream", y = "rating of charcoal") + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        legend.position = "bottom") +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)

# Make legend transparent
p3 <- p3 +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = c(NA, NA, NA)))) +
  theme(legend.text = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank())

p3 <- ggExtra::ggMarginal(p3, d1, type = "density",
                          margins = 'both',
                          size = 5,
                          groupColour = TRUE,
                          groupFill = TRUE,
                          position = "identity"
)

plot_row <- plot_grid(p1_1, p2, p3, nrow = 1)

# now add the title
title <- ggdraw() +
  draw_label(
    "Rating of Cream vs Charcoal",
    fontface = 'bold',
    x = 0,
    hjust = 0
  )

final <- plot_grid(
  title, plot_row,
  ncol = 1,
  # rel_heights values control vertical title margins
  rel_heights = c(0.1, 1)
)

final
```

[image]

**Note** Depending on the width and heigth of your plotting device, fixing the aspect ratio adds some white space at the top and bottom. Depending on your final output you probably have to play a bit around with the width and height (and scale), e.g. using

```r
ggsave("final.png", width = 18, height = 6, units = "cm", scale = 1.5)
```

gives

[image]

Comment: It worked nice, but the plot are elongated and not squares! , how to fix it, also how can I add back the "draw" to the plot, I tired to remove the filter, but it did not add the "draw", I wanted to replicate its shape and color, I did not realize it was included until I saw the legend down where it shows "winner, charcoal, cream, draw", with pink circle shape for charcoal, light green triangle for cream,  and light green square for draw.

Comment: Hi @user432797. I just made an edit. Adding the draw was easy. Simply remove the filter and add some shapes and colors for the draws. Tricky part was to get the plots square. To this end I switched to cowplot. But you probably still have to play around a bit the parameters to improve the final look.

Comment: Thank you so much @stefan, I appreciate your support. This was helpful, I was able to achieve the same results using `par(mfrow = c(3, 1))
nf <- layout(matrix(c(1,2,3),nrow=1), widths=c(2,2,2), heights=c(2,1,1), TRUE) `

Comment: but your code,  @stefan, is more sophisticated and cleaner than my line, again thank you so much for the assistance, it was really helpful to understand both the syntax and the flow of the code.